# Meteor update fails on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, meteor

I currently have Meteor 0.8.1.3 installed on my Windows 7 machine and I'm wanting to update it to the latest version (I believe to be 1.1 as of writing). I tried to run `meteor update` in my project directory but this generates the following error:

```
Failed to load tools for release 0.8.3
Failed to update Meteor.

C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\.meteor\tools\edf8981bb6\lib\node_modules\fibers\f
uture.js:173
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
[object Object]
```

In addition to a potential solution I'd also be interested to know the cause of the error too as I am relatively new to Meteor (having only briefly used it a while back hence the old version).

Comment: Your version is pretty old. I would suggest completely uninstalling Meteor and installing the latest version directly, then running `meteor update` in your project directory.

Comment: @Kyll Is there a suggested method of uninstallation for Windows? I know Windows support was previously shaky at best.

Comment: Through the control panel?

Comment: @Kyll Unfortunately it doesn't show up in my list of programs to uninstall.

Comment: Mh.. Do you see it with specialized software like http://geekuninstaller.com/ ?

Comment: @Kyll I had a look with CCleaner and it doesn't show up either

Comment: Maybe try to install the new version directly then. It should overwrite the old one, hopefully.